# LENOVO Ideapad 700 15ISK Instant Shutdown Using GPU While Power Plugged In

Tags: cpu, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-core-i7

I have a Lenovo Ideapad laptop. Dual boot Linux and Windows. Whenever I try to play games on Linux or Windows (game or OS does not matter), it's shuts down immediately. On power plugged battery. But PC doesn't shut down when battery not plugged in.

What have I tried:

- **Ran official Lenovo hardware tests in Lenovo Support Manager program.**

> PC shutdown when GPU stress test. PC shutdown when testing RAMs with MemTest86. No shutdown during RAM stress test.

- **Checked CPU's and GPU's temperatures and they are normal. They can't go up to 65 degree.**
- **Tried to lower clock frequency for GPU in MSI Afterburner program (when game starts, GPU starting overclock. I reduced frequency down to 870MHz. Overclock frequency is 1000MHz showing. In internet, peoples say -7MHz should be enough.).**
- **Replaced the CPU's and GPU's thermal pastes. (Two times) And no paste overflow over peripheral resistors or others.**
- **Cleaned fans.**
- **Reseted BIOS battery.**
- **In Windows, updated NVIDIA GTX950M drivers. Sometimes, game stucks, after 2 minutes game suddenly closes but PC doesn't shut down. And GPU drivers are broken. Can't reinstall driver until reboot. Or can't use the external GPU.**
- **Reinstalled games.**
- **Defragmented HDD (games are installed in HDD).**
- **Installed games to SSD. Problem still occurs.**
- **Linux says battery percentage is %82. After saw that removed battery and tried with only power adapter. Shuts down again.**
- **Changed RAM slots with each other. (16GB => 8+8 => 2133Mhz)**

I have a antivirus program on Windows. Kaspersky Internet Security 2019 Official Licenced. Scanned all disks and no sign for viruses.

Games I tried to play:

- Origin - Battlefield 3 (Windows)
- Steam - CS:GO (Linux and Windows)
- Steam - Europa Universalis (Linux)

HDD, battery and charger working properly. I can use PC how long I want without using GPU while charger plugged in. Battery can usable without charger up to 2 hours. I think it means battery works fine. But there is a mark for the charger while plugged in. When game starts, sometimes battery indicator LED flashing for 2 times. After making this 3 or 4 times PC is shuts down.

How can I fix this?
Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIX**: 
I fixed my problem in Windows using "NoteBook FanControl" and "MSI Afterburner" programs. I just lowered the frequencies of CPU and GPU. And set fan speeds to maximum.

**To lower the processor frequency in Windows 10:**

1 - Open "Power Options"

2 - Click"Change plan settings" for the plan you use

3 - Click "Change advanced power settings" on the page that opens.

4 - On the other page that opens, click on "Processor power management". You should now be seeing the "Minimum processor state", "System cooling policy" and "Maximum processor state".

4.1 - For "Minumum processor state"; set both settings to 5. (On battery: 5%, Plugged in: 5%)

4.2 - For "System cooling policy"; set "Plugged in" to "Active". You can set "On battery" same but it will reduce the working time of the computer on the battery.

4.3 - For "Maximum processor state"; set both settings to 75. (On battery: 75%, Plugged in 75%).

4.4 - Since the processor speed is reduced, the performance of the computer will also decrease. However, it will not turn itself off as it cannot heat up. If it is still shutting down, you will need to lower the maximum processor speed even further.

**To lower the GPU frequency in Windows 10:**

1 - Download and install the "MSI Afterburner" program from the official site.

2 - Reduce the "Core Clock (Mhz)" in the program as much as possible .For my laptop, I can lower the core clock speed by -135 Mhz.

3 - Reduce the "Memory Clock (Mhz)" in the program as much as possible too. For my laptop, I can lower memory clock  speed by -201 Mhz.

4 - Confirm the clock speeds you have set by clicking the tick below.

**To force fan speeds to the maximum:**

! IMPORTANT ! That can crash your computer because it writes values to registers. You will be responsible for any errors that will occur.

1 - Download and install the "NoteBook FanControl" program from the official site.

2 - Press "..." to the right of the "Selected config" section in the program and set "Config" to "Lenovo Ideapad 510s" on the page that opens and apply it.

3 - Set all "Target fan speed" to 100% and change "Fan control service status" from "Read-only" to "Enable".

And done. Your CPU and GPU frequencies lowered and computer's fans are working at maximum speed. Have a good game.

Comment: In Linux, I can both decrease the processor speed and use the "NoteBook FanControl" program. However, the computer suddenly shuts down because I couldn't lower the GPU frequency. If there is a solution that can lower the GPU frequency, I would appreciate it if you add it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how well this applies to your problem but I had this exact same issue with my Thinkpad W520. It turned out to be a faulty battery. (I guess it can't supply enough current and the motherboard decides to do an emergency poweroff)

Comment: Maybe you are right but when I called the service they said "you need to replace your motherboard, it looks like your GPU does it. And about the age of computer we don't produce new motherboards for that model so you need to find another private service for motherboard replacement." However I don't think so it happens because of battery. Because things are happening when computer is plugged in. I disabled the GPU in BIOS. Problem fixed for now but I cannot use discrete GPU.